# selenium chrome webdriver with toripchanger

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to open google search results whit selenium. I use toripchanger to change the ip iteratively.

```
tor_ip_changer = TorIpChanger(reuse_threshold=0,
                              local_http_proxy='127.0.0.1:8118')
ip = tor_ip_changer.get_new_ip()
current_ip = tor_ip_changer.get_current_ip()

PROXY = "%s:8118" % ip
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=https://%s' % PROXY)
browser = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver",
                           options=chrome_options)
browser_1 = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver",
                             options=chrome_options)

search_query = "microsoft site:instagram.com"
browser.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + search_query + "&start=" + str(10 * i))
```

But the driver cannot open the url. I dont get response from google.

Comment: First question: Does your proxy works?

Comment: @Wonka How should i check it? I run tor-proxy with docker: sudo docker run -it -p 8118:8118 -p 9050:9050 -d dperson/torproxy

Comment: To check it, if you have curl package: curl 'https://ifconfig.co/ip' (will return you IP) curl 'https://ifconfig.co/ip' -x 127.0.0.1:8118 (Will return proxy IP)

Comment: I dont recommend to post your IP's so delete you comment. Try to remove from your code "https://" from here --proxy-server=https:// ). Cause if you run curl 'ifconfig.co/ip' -x https://127.0.0.1:8118 It works??

Comment: @ Wonka It was not really my real ip actually, but thank for recommendation, i tried your solution, still not working ...

Answer (score 0):

After check proxy works, try this. Remove "https:// "

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
```